# How to show user profile photo in sharepoint view formatting?

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting

I would like to show the photo of a user based on a persons column via view formatting: here is the json snippet:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "img",
    "attributes": {
      "src": "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&AccountName=[$Person.email]"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it only shows a placeholder picture. It works if I subsitute [$Person.email] by the real mail adress.

Answer (score 0):

the source attribute was wrong. Correct is

"src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=' + [$Person.email]"